# beamer: Adding pause between two equations

Tags: beamer

```
 \documentclass{beamer}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    %-----
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts} %math
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   \usepackage{color}
     \usetheme{Madrid}

      \begin{document}

     \begin{frame}{}
      \begin{align*}
          \|x_n-x_m\|_B
          &=\|B(x_n-x_m)\|\pause\\
          &=\|y_n-y_m\|,
          \end{align*}
       \end{frame}

 \end{document}
```

> I want to get in the first time

[image]

and then

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I tried `\only{}` and `\uncover{}` and both seem to work.
- `\uncover{}` reserves the space (similar to `\phantom` I think).
- I removed some of your code since is has nothing to to with your question.

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\texttt{\textbackslash only\{\}}}

    \begin{align*}
        \|x_n-x_m\|_B
        &=\|B(x_n-x_m)\|\\
        \only<2>{&=\|y_n-y_m\|,}
    \end{align*}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\texttt{\textbackslash uncover\{\}}}

    \begin{align*}
        \|x_n-x_m\|_B
        &=\|B(x_n-x_m)\|\\
        \uncover<2>{&=\|y_n-y_m\|,}
    \end{align*}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

### Update after Comments

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\texttt{\textbackslash uncover<>\{\}}}

    \begin{align*}
        a + b (1-)\\
        \uncover<2-3>{a + b(2-3)\\}
        \uncover<4>{a + b(4)\\}
        \uncover<6->{a + b(6-)\\}
        \uncover<5>{a + b(5)\\}
    \end{align*}

    \only<7>{Text only in position 7.}
    % try \uncover to see the difference.

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Please why the number 2 here `\only<2>{`? because it is the second equation?

Comment: @Schüler Yes, have a look at the beamer manual if you want to know more (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer, see Chapter 9.3 Commands with Overlay Specifications
).

Comment: @Schüler You can accept my answer if your question is solved.

Comment: When I add `\uncover<2>{&=...}` in my original template, I remark that the second equation dispear after compilation.

Comment: @Schüler Then ask your question more specific :), you can try `\uncover<2->{...}` (`2-` instead of `2`)

Comment: I think that my question is clear. Even with `\uncover<2->{...}` my problem is not solved.

Comment: @Schüler Well, then I won't help further. I am active on this site for about 7 years now and answered over 230 questions: I try to help you, but you decide how you react to it. The output of my answer is exactly what you asked in your question in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Just I told you that when  I add \uncover<2>{&=...} in my original template, the second equation dispear and I don't understand where is the problem.

Comment: @Schüler See my update and then ask a new question that is clearer if necessary (different code). Your current question is answered as far as I am concerned.

Comment: @Schüler No, I have my own stuff to do for the rest of my day :). Have a look at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228 and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask in order to help yourself.