# beamer: Adding pause between two equations II

Tags: beamer

```
 \documentclass{beamer}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    %-----
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts} %math
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   \usepackage{color}
     \usetheme{Madrid}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    \begin{alertblock}{}

    \end{alertblock}
     \pause

      Let
     \pause
      \begin{align*}
    \|x_n-x_m\|_B
    &=\|B(x_n-x_m)\|\\
    \uncover<2>{&=\|y_n-y_m\|,}
    \end{align*}
   \pause
    \begin{alertblock}{}

     \end{alertblock}
     \end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

By using [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/492587/beamer-adding-pause-between-two-equations), I remark that the second equation dispear.

[image]

Comment: All the `\pause` were not part of the code in the previous question. Just count where the equation should appear and tell the `\uncover` command the number (add `-` if it should stay after the first appearance)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Try `<4->` in `\uncover<4->{&=\|y_n-y_m\|,}` or any other number
  depending on your wishes.
- And as in your previous question, you have a lot of unnecessary code.

All together with `uncover` instead of the last `pause`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{alertblock}{alertblock}
Text (1)
\end{alertblock}
\pause
Let (2)
\pause
\begin{align*}
\|x_n-x_m\|_B &=\|B(x_n-x_m)\| (3)\\
\uncover<4->{&=\|y_n-y_m\|, (4)}
\end{align*}
\uncover<5>{
\begin{alertblock}{alertblock}
Text (5)
\end{alertblock}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please what is the importance of the number `4` and the symbol `-` in `<4->`?

Comment: @Schüler This means "starting from slide 4 until the end of the frame".

Answer (score 1):

`\pause` doesn't work well in combination with `uncover`. I recommend you use `\onslide<+->` instead of `\pause`. In your example, you probably also want to use `\uncover<+->` instead of `\uncover<2>`.  With these changes you get:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%-----
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts} %math
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{alertblock}{}
\end{alertblock}
\onslide<+->
Let
\onslide<+->
\begin{align*}
\|x_n-x_m\|_B
&=\|B(x_n-x_m)\|\\
\uncover<+->{&=\|y_n-y_m\|,}
\end{align*}
\onslide<+->
\begin{alertblock}{}
\end{alertblock}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which seems to work well.

Generally speaking, if the sequence of your overlays follows your text, it suffices to use <+-> in your overlay commands (like \uncover<+->). Only when your overlay sequence becomes more complicated you need to specify numbers (like \uncover<2>).

Comment: +1: `\uncover<+->` is smarter :).

Comment: Thank you. However, I want to make a pause after the first block.

Comment: Then insert another \onslide<+-> before the first block.